# Problem with gcc installation from Homebrew

Tags: 22.04, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem with my gcc installation from Homebrew.

`homebrew install gcc` produces

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall gcc
```

`brew postinstall gcc` produces

```
==> Postinstalling gcc
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall gcc
```

`gcc --version` seems to have gcc version 11.3:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
```

`gcc-12 --version` gives this error:

```
-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12: Bad address
```

Because of this, many packages that are depended on gcc cannot run properly. Also, tried to install packages in R also fail. I tried reinstalling through homebrew with no success. Similarly, running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc` did not solve the problem.

Of note, I am running Ubuntu under WSL:

```
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19044.2364

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

echo $PATH

/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/dpkg/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/osekulovic/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/DNASTAR/Lasergene 17/SeqNinjaCL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/DNASTAR/Lasergene 17/ArrayStar:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/DNASTAR/Lasergene 17:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Pandoc/:/mnt/c/Users/sekulo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/sekulo/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin
```

Running `which gcc` produces

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Running `which gcc-12` produces

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
TP

Comment: Updated with Ubuntu and WSL versions.

Comment: Please include the output of "echo $PATH"  in your original posting.  Also the output of "which gcc"  gcc version 11.3 is the system default for gcc, and you should not change it (because many packages expect that version).  The gcc your user linuxbrew may override the system default by a PATH change.

Comment: Updated. You're right, I ran 'brew upgrade' and gcc got updated to gcc-12 among other things. If I uninstall gcc from homebrew, many packages do not work even if the system has gcc-11 and gcc-12 installed properly.

Comment: For the user linuxbrew, you may override the system gcc by putting a symbolic link in the user's bin directory (make it if not there).  cd ~/bin ;  ln -s /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12 gcc     Then which gcc for that user only should get the 12 version.

Comment: cd /usr/bin/ then ln -s /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12 gcc produces the following: ln: failed to create symbolic link 'gcc': File exists

Comment: Wrong location for cd.   ~/bin is really /home/linuxbrew/bin, not /usr/bin.  mkdir bin in your home if it does not exist.

Comment: Successfully done; ```which gcc``` produces ```usr/bin/gcc```, ```which gcc-12``` produces ```/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12```; running ```gcc-12 --version``` has the same error: ```-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12: Bad address```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue may be that you're missing some of the Homebrew requirements as documented under [Homebrew on Linux - Requirements](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux#requirements):

> Requirements
>
> ```
> Linux 3.2 or newer
> Glibc 2.13 or newer
> 64-bit x86_64 CPU
> ```
>
> To install build tools, paste at a terminal prompt:
>
> Debian or Ubuntu
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential procps curl file git
> ```

This seemed to then allow the gcc post-install command to work:

```
$ brew postinstall gcc                                     
==> Postinstalling gcc
==> Creating the GCC specs file: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/specs
```